# EntityManagerFactory is null During Application Startup (Java EE6 with JBoss)

Tags: hibernate, jboss6.x

I am having problems deploying a Java EE 6 application on JBoss 6. The startup process works fine until after the persistence unit is bound to its JNDI name. The DB connection has been established.

Then I get an error, saying

```
2012-01-26 13:29:31,451 ERROR [org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelController] (HDScanner) Error installing to Create: name=jboss.j2ee:jar=Content_Hub.war,name=AgofResource,service=EJB3 state=Configured: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: EntityManagerFactory cannot be null
```

Can anyone provide a clue, what might cause this error?

**Update**:

Here is my persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="cmsPU" transaction-type="JTA">
  <jta-data-source>java:/tteamdb</jta-data-source>
  <class>xxxx.entity.AgofEntry</class>
  <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
  <properties>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="xxxx" />
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect" />
    <!-- user/pass for DB , too-->  
  </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Data source is also configured in JBoss.

I tried to add a components.xml, but that does not seem to affect the error in any way:

```
<components xmlns="http://jboss.com/products/seam/components" xmlns:persistence="http://jboss.com/products/seam/persistence">
  <persistence:entity-manager-factory name="entityManagerFactory" persistence-unit-name="cmsPU" />
  <persistence:managed-persistence-context name="em" auto-create="true" entity-manager-factory="#{entityManagerFactory}" />
</components>
```

I am actually not using an EntityManagerFactory anywhere. Just a plain EntityManager like this:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "cmsPU")
private EntityManager em;
```

Comment: Can you show some code where you inject your EMF and how it's configured in `persistence.xml`?

Comment: Just shooting here - you're using the JNDI name of application server's DataSource and at the same time you're providing Hibernate-specific connection url properties. Perhaps it generates the problem?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I only added the connection properties to persistence.xml because JBoss somehow does not remember username and password of the DS configured in the console. I am sure I am just doing something stupid, but I cannot see what.

Comment: One question I have: is the components.xml required, or can I just drop that file? I only added it during debugging to see if that works.

Comment: I didn't use Seam framework, so if you're not using it - it's not needed. However, if you're using Seam framework - I have no idea what will happen if you'll delete it ;-) BTW: Where do you inject your EntityManager? EJB? If you don't inject it - will the error still occur?

Comment: I remain clueless. I moved the data source to a server-deployed foo-ds.xml  file, removed login data in persistence.xml and removed all @PersistenceContext injections. Still same error. Why is the container trying to access the entity manager factory on startup anyhow? What would be the reason for the EMF to be null?

Comment: By now, I created a toy project and isolated the error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9042032/problems-with-stateless-and-application-startup-on-jboss-6

Comment: Jan, just for tests - does the same error occur in JBoss AS7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurred only in the particular installation of JBoss. Worked fine with a local install. I'll post a comment should I ever find the reason for the error.